# Catch Exception from Method Reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I’m trying to pass a method reference which throws a checked Exception:

```
Files.list((Paths.get("/some/path"))).map(Files::readAllLines);
```

How can I handle this exception (without wrapping the method reference in a method which handles the exeption).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're attempting to catch an exception for a specific value in the `.map` I wouldn't recommend a method reference, instead use a lambda:

```
Files.list((Paths.get("/some/path"))).map((someVal) -> {

    try {
        //do work with 'someVal'
    } catch (YourException ex) {
        //handle error
    }

});
```

If you want to rethrow the exception after, you can do so manually with a reference to the error through a box:

```
//using the exception itself
final Box<YourException> e = new Box<>();
Files.list((Paths.get("/some/path"))).map((someVal) -> {

    try {
        //do work with 'someVal'
    } catch (YourException ex) {
        //handle error
        e.setVar(ex);
    }

});
if (e.getVar() != null) {
    throw e.getVar();
}

class Box<T> {
    private T var;
    public void setVar(T var) { this.var = var; }
    public T getVar() { return this.var; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works! But apart from the recommendation - is there a way to catch/rethrow a exception here?

Comment: Depends, if you're wanting to rethrow an exception after-the-fact, then you can simply use a `boolean` to trigger throwing one after (since throwing mid-iteration will stop the progress).

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood you correct. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I changed my mind a little, you can just "cache" the last exception thrown and re-throw it after if need be. I updated my answer to show it.

Comment: Ahem, your second example is completely broken. It’s one of the fundamental principle that you can **not** use a lambda to write into local variables of the surrounding context. You remember, lambdas capture `final` variables or “effectively `final`” variables only?

Comment: Ah, forgot about it being an anonymous context. I'll update with a new way in a moment here.